# Routing with areas and different parameters, misunderstanding

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, routes

I have been confused all day, i have a routing in area and it looks like this.

```
public class AdminAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration
{
    public override string AreaName
    {
        get
        {
            return "admin";
        }
    }

    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        context.MapRouteLowercase(null, "Account/{action}",
                                  new {controller = "Account"},
                                  new {action = @"LogOff|LogOn|Create|Update|Delete|List"},
                                  new[] {"WebUI.Areas.Admin.Controllers"});

        context.MapRouteLowercase( //this works
            "AdminUpdateCategoryView",
            "admin/{controller}/{action}/{cid}",
            new {area = "admin", controller = "Main", action = "UpdateCategory", cid = ""},
            new {cid = @"\d+"},
            new[] {"WebUI.Areas.Admin.Controllers"}
        );

        context.MapRouteLowercase(//this not works
            "AdminCategoryListView",
            "admin/Main/{action}/{page}",
            new { action = "Category", page = "1" },
            new {page = @"\d+"},
            new[] {"WebUI.Areas.Admin.Controllers"}
        );

        context.MapRouteLowercase(
            "Admin_Default", // Route name
            "admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new {controller = "Category", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional} // Parameter defaults
        );
    }
}
```

I have wrote what works and what not, but if change between them the one that doesn't work, works and the other that works, don't work?

example:

> ```
> first case-> /admin/main/updatecategory/1 --> works 
>              /admin/main/category/1       --> not works
>              result: /admin/main/category/1?page=1
>
> second case-> /admin/main/category/1 --> works
>               /admin/main/updatecategory/1 --> not works
>               result: /admin/main/updatecategory/1?cid=1
> ```

Here is my controller actions:

```
public ActionResult Category(int? page)
    {
        int pageIndex = page.HasValue ? page.Value : 1;
        return View("Category", CategoryViewModelFactory(pageIndex));
    }

    public ActionResult CreateCategory()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult UpdateCategory(int cid)
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult DeleteCategory(int? cid)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

What is this problem and how to solve it?

I'm totally confused, Routing in ASP.MVC3 is e-logical.

Help?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When routes are searched, the first one that matches your URL is used. `AdminUpdateCategoryView` will match any admin controller, and action. You provide a default cid of "", but that shouldn't matter because you're requiring that cid be a number below that. `AdminCategoryListView` will match any url that enters main. Because you provide a default page of 1, it doesn't even matter if no page is provided.

So if `AdminCategoryListView` is on top: every single route in admin/main will use this route.
If `AdminUpdateCategoryView` is on top every route in admin that reaches this route and has a numerical cid value parameter will use it.

I'd recommend putting `AdminCategoryListView` on top because it's the more specific route. Either remove `page="1"` (depends on if you want to provide a default), or replace `{action}` with "category" so your other routes don't use this route. Also you should provide a default controller of main, otherwise it will assume the controller you're currently using is the correct one.

```
context.MapRouteLowercase(
        "AdminCategoryListView",
        "admin/Main/category/{page}",
        new { action = "Category", controller = "Main" },
        new {page = @"\d+"},
        new[] {"WebUI.Areas.Admin.Controllers"}
    );

//Put AdminUpdateCategoryView here
```